# Letting users vote for one node per category

Tags: 7, rating

I'm working on a D7 site for a yearly "Best of town"-style competition, with businesses submitting listings (Each a node and placed in a taxonomy) and users voting on their favourite node in each of the six categories in the aforementioned taxonomy.

Drupal seems to have a lot of voting modules geared towards ranking stuff out of x (I.e., fivestar) but less so for choosing one (and only one) node in a series of categories. Any idea how I'd do that?

Thanks!